# requestWithGraphPath Method doesn't return username field

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Since the end of the first week of May 2015, the  facebook module function requestWithGraphPath method doesn't return username field anymore (es. john.smith.18@facebook.com).

I'm developing with titanium and that is my code:

```
 fb.requestWithGraphPath('me', {}, 'GET', function(e) {
    if (e.success) {
        Titanium.API.info(e.result);
    }
```

this is the output:

```
{"link":"http://www.facebook.com/10000576745____","id":"10000576745___","first_name":"Marco","name":"Marco ______","gender":"male","last_name":"____","locale":"it_IT","timezone":1,"verified":false,"updated_time":"2013-04-27T10:11:08+0000"}
```

Username field is missing.

Did Facebook changed anything inside the method? Now I can collect only First Name, Last Name, ID, as user identifier fields, but my app uses username field at all!
Any suggestion?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The username field was deprecated and is no longer available.